# The system $2XY+X^2+Y^2+X^2Y+Y+XY^2+X=0$, for distinct pairs $X, Y\in\{J, K, L\}$ for $n$th roots of unity $J, K, L$.

Tags: nonlinear-system, roots-of-unity

> Solve the system $(I)$ of equations
>   $$\begin{align}
> 2JK+J^2+K^2+J^2K+K+JK^2+J &=0,\tag{$Ia$} \\
> 2KL+K^2+L^2+K^2L+L+KL^2+K &=0,\tag{$Ib$} \\
> 2LJ+L^2+J^2+L^2J+J+LJ^2+L &=0\tag{$Ic$}
> \end{align}$$ for $J, K, L$. Assume that $J, K, L$ are $n$th roots of unity for some $n\in\Bbb N$.

*My Attempt:*

By symmetry in $(I)$, we have $J=K=L$, so that, from $(Ia)$,

$$2K^2+K^2+K^2+K^3+K+K^3+K=0,$$

*i.e.*, $2K^3+4K^2+2K=0$, which gives $K=0$ or $K=-1$. But $K\neq 0$.

Thus the solutions to $(I)$ are given by $J=K=L=-1$.

> Is this the only solution?

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symmetry in the system does not imply that the three variables are equal. All factor, you have
$$  (J+K)(1+J)(1+K) = 0, $$
$$  (K+L)(1+K)(1+L) = 0, $$
$$  (L+J)(1+L)(1+J) = 0. $$

If all $J,K,L \neq -1$ the remaining linear system says $J,K,L = 0.$

If $L = -1$ but $J,K \neq -1$ then $K = -J$ are anything, as long as $J,K \neq 1$ either. They are saying roots of unity, sure, why not.

If $L,K = -1$ then $J$ is anything at all.